# Google Tag Manager Preview mode does not work in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application, aurelia, google-tag-manager

I've added the google tag manager to the aurelia skeleton application.
I can create tags in the GTM and the app fires the events which I can see in the Google Analytics dashboard.
The problem is that the preview mode does not work.
The iframe shows up while the app is loading and then disappears.
What could be the cause of this?
Does preview mode work in a Single Page Application?

Here's the link of the Aurelia App with GTM:
https://sofoklism.github.io/spm/#/

Comment: This happens to me often too and I hope someone can give a solid answer. In the past clearing cookies and changing browser often helps but this doesn't really seem like a solution. If you figure it out do share

Comment: I've tried clearing cookies or using different browsers, none of it worked.

Comment: Just to confirm, if you open the console and type google_tag_manager an object does appear - i.e. gtm is def on the page?

Comment: Yes an object appears. The container id is there. It looks correct.

Comment: Are you able to share a preview link? In GTM under preview there's an option to do that

Comment: https://www.googletagmanager.com/set_cookie?uiv2&id=GTM-N6M22DL&gtm_auth=OTEI-0byaQjecZ3rcwH2Tg&gtm_preview=env-5&gtm_debug=x

Comment: Ok try the link I just sent. I shared the preview

Comment: Thanks, yes I see your issue. Sorry but I cannot help! I see the preview pane open for  a moment then disappear. If you don't get any help on here I recommend trying the GTM Google + community they tend to be more responsive on this particular topic that stack overflow GTM tag

Comment: Ok, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `aurelia-app="main"` from the `<body>` to another element, a `<div>` for example.

```
<body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div aurelia-app="main">
    <div class="splash"><!-- ... --></div>
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Aurelia replaces the content of the app host element, so any content added before `.setRoot` completes gets removed.
This is how the splash screen gets removed.